# A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.Int32' and 'Edm.Int32' for operator kind 'And'

Tags: azure, t-sql, xamarin, azure-sql-database, azure-mobile-services

When I query my Azure DB via IMobileServiceClient from my mobile App, I get the following error for the query:

```
https://domain.azurewebsites.net/tables/Entities?$filter=(substringof('f',OriginalName) and ((Types and 1) ne 0))&$orderby=Start&$skip=0&$top=20&$select=OriginalName,OriginalSlogan,Description,Start,End,Types,Id,Version,CreatedAt,UpdatedAt,Deleted

The query specified in the URI is not valid. A binary operator with incompatible types was detected. Found operand types 'Edm.Int32' and 'Edm.Int32' for operator kind 'And'."
```

However when querying the DB directly with

```
Select * from Entities where ((Types & 1) <> 0)
```

it works fine.

In [Transact-SQL Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/sql/t-sql/language-elements/bitwise-operators-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) it is stated that the bitwise and operator is valid for two ints (which are 32 bit types). [OData Doc](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/overview/) states that edm.Int32 represents a signed 32-bit integer value.

The essential part of my query within my app is

```
query = query.Where(f => (f.TypesDb & types) != 0);
```

Both `f.TypesDb` and `types` are ints in C# code. (Note: `f.TypesDb` is mapped to `Types` through json serialization)

So why are the types incompatible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMobileServiceClient translates `&` in code incorrectly to `and` in the URL filter parameter. 
`and` is interpreted as *logical and*, so type `Edm.Int32` is incompatible with that.

There is no way to use a *bitwise and* in the filter parameter of the URL.

As a dirty workaround I do now store a comma separated string of `int`s in the database and parse it back instead of storing an integer that represents a `flag enum`.